# Python - print out a visual recursion trace

Tags: python, recursion

I have this code that is doing recursion but I want to be able to watch the recursions but illustrate the depth of each recursions and also when it comes back out. Just something simple as shown below. Not sure where I need to put spaces or tabs to make this happened and I'm using a string map_str and then printing it out at the end.   Please see code and example of output.

```
def get_process_parents(batchDate, late_process):
    global late_parents
    global map_str
    process_depends = []
    #logging.info('late_process: %s ' % late_process)
    process_depends = getprocessDependencies(batchDate, late_process)
    late_parents[late_process.get('name')] = process_depends
    map_str += (' %s ---> %s \n------>\n' % (late_process.get('name'), process_depends))
    #logging.info('Late_process Name: %s ---> Depends: %s ' % (late_process.get('name'),process_depends))
    if not process_depends:
        #logging.info('No more depends: %s' % late_process.get('name'))
        late_parents_process.add(late_process.get('name'))
        map_str += (' %s ---> %s\n ---->\n' % (late_process.get('name'), process_depends))
    else:
        for process_depend in process_depends:
            process = getprocessByName(batchDate, process_depend)
            #logging.info('process_depend %s --> state: %s ' % (process_depend, process.get('state')))
            if process.get('state') == 'Done':
                #logging.info('process depend DONE: %s' % process_depend)
                map_str += (' %s Status: %s\n ---->\n' % (process_depend, process.get('state')))

            else:
                late_parents_process.add(process.get('name'))
                get_process_parents(batchDate, getprocessByName(batchDate,process_depend))
```

Output:

What I want it to look like

```
 Process_name ----> ['process dependencies 1', 'process dependencies 2'] 
------>process dependencies 1 ---->  [process dependencies 3, dependencies 4] 
       ------>dependencies 3 -----> []
       ------>dependencies 4 -----> []
------>process dependencies 2 ---->  [process dependencies 5] 
       ------>process dependencies 5 -----> [process dependencies 6] 
              ----->process dependencies 6 -----> []
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you alter the function signature? If so, then the easiest way would be to define the function as:

```
def get_process_parents(batchDate, late_process, depth=0):
```

and then in your nested calls use

```
get_process_parents(batchDate, getprocessByName(batchDate,process_depend), depth + 1)
```

Then, to indent, you can use:

```
print '\t' * depth + ('%s---->... # etc, etc
```

I'd caution against using a global for map_str if you can avoid it.

Comment: What are so things to look out for using global in this context?

Comment: In general, global variables, which can change outside the scope of your function, make your code harder to reason about. In this case, you have to make sure that map_str gets properly reset between calls to your function. If you use `depth` as above, you could put in a line like 'if depth==0: map_str=""`, which would make it somewhat safer and less error prone.